# Google Analytics Paypal Buy button event not firing

Tags: paypal, google-analytics

I am trying to track clicks on a Paypal order button, my code looks like this....

```
<form onclick="_gag.push(['_trackEvent','Category','Action','Label']);" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="FV4TYGHXWUGHT">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Item">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.00"><input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.mydomain.com/notify.html">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mydomain.com/return.html">
<input type="image" src="http://www.mydomain.com/images/buynow.png" name="submit"/>
<img style="margin-top:20px;" alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

This doesn't work and no event is fired when clicked, analytics is working fine on the page other wise and if I use this....

```
<a href="http://www.testurl.com" target="_blank" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Click-Through', 'Test1', 'Test2']);">TEST LINK</a>
```

It works fine and I can see the event reported in realtime analytics

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem you are facing that the page navigation happens before GA has had the time to fire the event. You can use the example provided on [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en) page to solve your problem.

First, Add following to the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function trackOutboundLink(form, category, action, label) {

try {
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category , action, label]);
} catch(err){}

  setTimeout(function() {
    form.submit();
  }, 100);
}
</script>
```

Then, Change your tracking as follows:

```
<form onsubmit="trackOutboundLink(this, 'category', 'action', 'label'); return false;" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
```

**Note that I have not tested this but I know that something like this should work. Once you try this and it does not work, let me know and I can find if something is wrong here.

Comment: Perfect, that worked exactly how I wanted it.  Thanks for the link and code!

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: [onclick is a valid attribute for a form](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp), I would still use onsumbit. Instead of placing the onsubmit on the `<form>` tag itself, place it on the `input`

```
<input type="image" onclick="_gag.push(['_trackEvent','Category','Action','Label']);" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" src="http://www.mydomain.com/images/buynow.png" name="submit"/>
```

Comment: I have already tried with onsubmit and that is not working for me either :(